# House started creaking a lot recently

Tags: walls, wood

House getting more creaky recently

We bought a 20 year old house in January of this year. It’s in Toronto, Canada.

I wonder if following issues are seasonal as it’s the only explanation I can think of, since structural engineer ruled out foundation issues being the cause.

1. After a few months of moving in, especially when it started to get hot and humid outside, we noticed floors and stairs became a lot more creaky and squeaky.
2. In last couple of months, the kitchen island started separating from the wall it’s attached to and there’s creaking sound coming from that wall when we walk around the island. The kitchen floor is pretty level, confirmed with structural engineer. Quite frequently, there’s also banging sounds from under floor in kitchen when we’re walking around kitchen. It sounds like 2 heavy pieces of wood hitting each other, or wood on metal, it’s difficult to describe.
3. Since about 2 weeks ago, there’s creaking from under the carpet in 2 rooms, when walking on top of specific areas. In one room, the noise comes both from both under the carpet as well as the wall nearby.

When we moved in back in January, it was very dry inside, around 25-30% RH. Replaced non-functional bypass humidifier right away and it came around 40% after a few weeks. Since about May it’s been around 55% on average, never beyond 60%. We run AC for 8-12 hrs a day.

I wonder if above issues are related to humidity change. The previous owner says that they didn’t have these issues. However, I don’t entirely believe they even occupied this house. Seems like an investor owned it, so there’s a chance it was sitting empty for a few years and with our long winters, it was very dry for most of the time. The structural engineer is saying there’s no huge concern with foundation/structure and wouldn’t be the cause of above issues. I’m at a loss, my hope is it’s seasonal and I just need a carpenter to fix the flooring and mounting for the island.

Comment: What type of house construction is it?  I live in a true timberframe house and creaks and snaps all the time, esp. with wind and large temp swings.

Comment: Unless you don't trust the SE who was physically there (in which case, I'd suggest calling in a different one for a 2nd opinion), I'd suggest that you don't have anything to worry about, it's just annoying. I doubt that anyone sitting on the other side of a screen is going to be able to give you an answer that will build more confidence. 20% humidity to 55-60% is a pretty big swing. It's entirely possible that it's just the house moving because that's what wood does.

Comment: Issue #1 and #3 sound like effects of increased humidity. Issue #2 is odd. The island moving is probably due to seasonal wood movement as well, but the "banging sounds" are probably something else. Heh, maybe poltergeists?

Comment: I can tell the time of year w/o a calendar just by walking around my 130-year-old house, ex my stairs are quiet in the summer, creaky in the winter, the opposite of the dining room. cest la vie.

Comment: Thanks everybody for your comments. I’ll see if it gets worse over next few weeks and maybe get a second opinion from another SE. It’s just crazy how it got a lot creakier recently, but hopefully it’s to do with a very hot and humid summer we’ve been having.